# Should a single function with a set number of possible outcomes be broken up into separate functions in Python?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

For example, the following function moves
a player a given amount based on the direction
passed:

```
def move(player, direction, amount):
    if direction == 'up':
        player.y -= amount
    elif direction == 'down':
        player.y += amount
    elif direction == 'left':
        player.x -= amount
    elif direction == 'right':
        player.x += amount
```

Instead of passing the direction as a string, should
the function be broken down into four smaller functions?

```
def move_up(player, amount):
    player.y -= amount

def move_down(player, amount):
    player.y += amount

def move_left(player, amount):
    player.x -= amount

def move_right(player, amount):
    player.x += amount
```

Comment: it's up to you, i'd say.

Comment: Is `player` a instance of a class ?

Comment: yes, player is an instance of a class.

Comment: This is a matter of preference.

Comment: I would say keep them as separate methods. Its clean and allows for future changes to be easily made. Though ultimately its up to you.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/curlys-law-do-one-thing/ The more modular your code is, the easier it is to refactor and debug. Basically the second way is better coding practice in modern times. :) But the first way will obviously use less memory and perhaps less keystrokes. Tradeoffs everywhere!

Comment: It depends on what you consider to be "one thing." Personally, I think "move" is one thing with any specified direction, in the same way that `print()` is one thing with objects of any specified `type` (unlike in, say, MIPS, which has different codes to print an int, a character, a string, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd do:

```
def move(player, x, y):
    player.x += x
    player.y += y
```

If the player moves left or up, the corresponding argument is negative. If the player does not move on a given axis, the corresponding argument is zero. Additionally, this makes it easier to add diagonal movement without having to add more `move()` calls and direction checks.

Comment: This is the smartest approach but the OP was just using that as an example. I believe he is looking for a broader answer. (However, then the question is opinionated which is frowned upon on stack overflow)

Comment: yes, broader answer is correct but that is a good approach.

Comment: I think it does provide a broad answer: if you're faced with two options that you don't really like, go back to the drawing board and look for a cleaner, more extensible solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's mostly preference. In cases where the code is larger, then separating methods makes sense. Let's say you had the same move function except inside it you got some path finding, friction, and other procedures. At that point, you'd could expect some performance loss for including all of the possible outcomes in one function. What is even more detrimental is you get confusing code. It gets cluttered and hard to read.

Personally, in your case, I'd have one function to control all possible outcomes. It seems best to me to make your code more concise. I also personally feel that **methods that can handle more scenarios rather than having more methods to handle more scenarios are better** (As long as you don't lose to much performance). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of preference, in fact you could accomplish the same result with indices of a list:

```
player.x += [-1, 1, 0, 0][['left', 'right', 'up', 'down'].index(direction)] * amount
player.y += [0, 0, -1, 1][['left', 'right', 'up', 'down'].index(direction)] * amount
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by giants of industry, like Martin Fowler, Kent Beck, Eric Gamma, Robert C. Martin and actually every experienced programmer:

Each function or method should do one and only one thing.
And the smaller function is the better it.

In your case it is really not important because amount of code is small, but in real world applications it makes big difference.

I hardly recommend you to look at least at 'Refactoring' by M.Fowler, 'Clean code' by R.C.Martin; books like so you can google with no problem and you will find out why it is really better to keep functions small.

Or you can follow above guys advices and spent years writing sloppy code and finally figure out on your own why it is better to keep methods tight.

Comment: In this case, all of those functions do one thing: move the player. Parameters can specify the nature of that movement.